# Вывести всех клиентов, у которых в поле type есть значения и 1 и 2

Tags: sql, foxpro

Есть таблица tmp с полями num, fio, service, type.

В поле service могут быть значения: Сборка ПК со скидкой, Сборка ПК, Ремонт ПК, Ремонт ПК со скидкой
В поле type могут быть значения 1 и 2.

Для Сборка ПК со скидкой, Сборка ПК оно 1
Для Ремонт ПК, Ремонт ПК со скидкой оно 2

Нужно получить все записи (клиентов), которым делались услуги с type 1 и 2, т.е. оба типа услуг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычное реляционное деление.

Comment: Как делить? подскажите пожалуйста. Понятно что нужно использовать group by и Having count, н о не могу понять как

Comment: Какая у вас база данных? MS SQL Server, MySQL, и т.п.

Comment: Каков ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это сделать в MS SQL Server.

Алгоритм очень прост.

(1) Счетчик количества услуг обоих типов для клиента в каждой записи внутри CTE. Таким образом, мы получаем поля **TotalType1** и **TotalType2**.

(2) Второй SELECT проверяет наличие обоих типов услуг. И отфильтровывает записи, когда это не так через предложение `WHERE TotalType1 > 0 AND TotalType2 > 0`

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, num INT, fio NVARCHAR(20), [service] NVARCHAR(30), [type] INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (num, fio, [service], [type])
VALUES
(444, N'Иванов', N'Сборка ПК', 1),
(444, N'Иванов', N'Сборка ПК со скидкой', 1),
(444, N'Иванов', N'Ремонт ПК', 2),
(444, N'Иванов', N'Ремонт ПК со скидкой', 2),
(445, N'Петров', N'Сборка ПК со скидкой', 1),
(445, N'Петров', N'Ремонт ПК', 2),
(555, N'Васильев', N'Ремонт ПК', 2),
(332, N'Михайлов', N'Сборка ПК', 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , SUM(IIF(type=1,1,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY num) AS TotalType1
        , SUM(IIF(type=2,1,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY num) AS TotalType2
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE TotalType1 > 0 AND TotalType2 > 0
ORDER BY ID;
```

> Вывод

```
+----+-----+--------+----------------------+------+------------+------------+
| ID | num |  fio   |       service        | type | TotalType1 | TotalType2 |
+----+-----+--------+----------------------+------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 444 | Иванов | Сборка ПК            |    1 |          2 |          2 |
|  2 | 444 | Иванов | Сборка ПК со скидкой |    1 |          2 |          2 |
|  3 | 444 | Иванов | Ремонт ПК            |    2 |          2 |          2 |
|  4 | 444 | Иванов | Ремонт ПК со скидкой |    2 |          2 |          2 |
|  5 | 445 | Петров | Сборка ПК со скидкой |    1 |          1 |          1 |
|  6 | 445 | Петров | Ремонт ПК            |    2 |          1 |          1 |
+----+-----+--------+----------------------+------+------------+------------+
```

> FoxPro SQL

```
SELECT a.* FROM @tbl AS a
    INNER JOIN 
(SELECT num
    , SUM(IIF(type=1,1,0)) AS TotalType1
    , SUM(IIF(type=2,1,0)) AS TotalType2
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY num
HAVING SUM(IIF(type=1,1,0)) > 0 AND SUM(IIF(type=2,1,0)) > 0) AS b
    ON a.num = b.num
```

Comment: У меня в foxpro таблица. Обычным SQL как отобрать? В foxpro не работает данный запрос

Comment: @Kolhoznik, Я обновил ответ для FoxPro.

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее пояснить запрос для фокспро. Что как считается тут

Comment: @Kolhoznik, Чтобы лучше это понять, вам нужно запустить вложенный SELECT с псевдонимом b и без предложения `HAVING SUM(IIF(type=1,1,0)) > 0 AND SUM(IIF(type=2,1,0)) > 0`

Comment: Да да уже разобрался. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT fio
FROM tmp
WHERE type IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY fio
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=688738a0c261c90090af0a1d41afae87)

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так, например, отобрать fio. А дальше можно и записи все по fio отобрать.

```
select distinct f.fio from tmp f
join tmp t1 on t1.fio = f.fio and t1.type = 1
join tmp t2 on t2.fio = f.fio and t2.type = 2
```

Или так:

```
select distinct t1.fio from tmp t1
join tmp t2 on t2.fio = t1.fio
where t1.type = 1 and t2.type = 2
```

Comment: так пишет что fio не уникально

Comment: добавил поле id уникальное и пробовал так select distinct * from tmp t1 join tmp t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.type_s = 1 and t1.type_s = 2 но ничего не выдает запрос

Comment: Ай, я ошибся, в обоих запросах там в конце разных таблиц type должен на номер проверяться, я исправил

Comment: А id - это чей id записи о работе или клиента?

Comment: Ещё исправил - уточнил, какой таблицы fio брать в select-е

Comment: id записи добавил

Comment: Пробую ваш второй вариант запроса, но он не все записи выводит в результат. В вопрос добавил кусок таблицы. В результате только данные с id 1,2,5. А например с id 3 и 6 нет, хотя должны быть.

Answer (score 0):

может `GROUP_CONCAT(type SEPARATOR ' ') ... GROUP BY fio`, а потом уже из него `LIKE`